# Deleting rows of repetitive recordings from RFID data set

Tags: r

I have a RFID data sequence. Every row contains a time stamp and an ID. I want to delete repetitive recordings. The data looks like this

```
Row ID  Date     Time
1   A   1-13    12:03:11
2   B   1-13    12:03:12
3   A   1-13    12:06:06
4   B   1-13    12:16:25
5   A   1-13    12:16:52
6   A   1-13    12:16:53
7   A   1-13    12:16:54
8   B   1-13    12:39:46
9   B   1-13    12:41:20
10  B   1-13    12:41:20
11  B   1-13    12:41:21
12  B   1-13    12:42:20
13  B   1-13    12:42:24
14  A   1-13    12:51:37
15  A   1-13    12:51:38
```

I want to delete those rows that show a recording that has been done during the same second as the recording in the row above, OR one second later. So in this case I want to delete row 2,6,7,10,11 and 15.

Can someone help me with a code that does this automatically in the whole data set?

Comment: Do you mean something like `unique(df)` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your date column using `as.POSIXct` and then apply `diff` to have the time differences, e.g

```
v <- c("1-13 12:03:11", "1-13 12:03:12", "1-13 12:06:06", "1-13 12:16:25", 
       "1-13 12:16:52", "1-13 12:16:53", "1-13 12:16:54", "1-13 12:39:46", 
       "1-13 12:41:20", "1-13 12:41:20", "1-13 12:41:21", "1-13 12:42:20", 
       "1-13 12:42:24", "1-13 12:51:37", "1-13 12:51:38")
ind <- diff(as.POSIXct(v, format = "%m-%d %T")) <= 1
ind
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Then you can remove the rows by subsetting

```
# suppose your data frame is labelled df
df[!c(FALSE, ind),]    # first row should be kept
```

Comment: Great!! Thank you!! With the diff() function I can make it work!

Answer (score 1):

And A `dplyr` option. Convert `Time` to date-time object, `arrange` by `Time` and `filter` only those rows which have difference of more than 1 second to previous row.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Time1 = as.POSIXct(Time, format = "%T")) %>%
  arrange(Time1) %>%
  filter(c(TRUE, diff(Time1) > 1)) %>%
  select(-Time1)

#  Row ID Date     Time
#1   1  A 1-13 12:03:11
#2   3  A 1-13 12:06:06
#3   4  B 1-13 12:16:25
#4   5  A 1-13 12:16:52
#5   8  B 1-13 12:39:46
#6   9  B 1-13 12:41:20
#7  12  B 1-13 12:42:20
#8  13  B 1-13 12:42:24
#9  14  A 1-13 12:51:37
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly "hacky" solution:

```
library(dplyr)
new_df<-df %>% 
  mutate(To_Split=unlist(as.numeric(lapply(strsplit(df$Time,":"),function(x) x[3]))))


  new_df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(To_Split),list(function(x) x==lag(x)|x==(lag(x)+1))) %>% 
  filter(To_Split==FALSE|is.na(To_Split)) %>% 
  select(-To_Split)
```

Result:

```
 Row ID Date     Time
1   1  A 1-13 12:03:11
2   3  A 1-13 12:06:06
3   4  B 1-13 12:16:25
4   5  A 1-13 12:16:52
5   8  B 1-13 12:39:46
6   9  B 1-13 12:41:20
7  12  B 1-13 12:42:20
8  13  B 1-13 12:42:24
9  14  A 1-13 12:51:37
```